# Need to understand some general things about Apache, MySQL, phpmyadmin, php

Tags: php, mysql, apache, phpmyadmin, root

For last 3 days I've been trying to solve a simple thing, even asked on this website, still haven't got an accurate answer, I'm pretty lost now and my head is going to explode from all this new information, firstly I need get to know how to fix this:

> Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost' (using password: NO).

I know that there are many threads about this but I need a lot more answers.

1. How this problem above is fixed? Please don't tell me to use some kind of code like "mysql -u root -p" because that leads to 2nd question.
2. If I would use the command above(mysql -u root -p) WHERE do I have to write it in? I mean I have just installed Apache, phpmyadmin, MySQL and php on my computer I haven't even connected it to my website yet(if I have to).
3. What Apache is actually for?What is the purpose of using it?Why would I use it instead of just having my website on any other folder?In which folder should I put my website in(I was thinking about C:\Apache24\htdocs,is that correct?)?
4. Will my configurations work on my website phpmyadmin(which I got when I bought domain which is www.****.com/phpmyadmin) if I haven't connected it to my phpmyadmin which is in apache directory?

I might ask pretty stupid questions, but please don't judge me, I came to learn, and the purpose of this website is to help, not to flame on others, right?Thanks!By the way,I'm using Windows 7.

Comment: The purpose of this site is to solve [concrete and specific] problems, which may lead you to learn something of course, but as a side effect. In order to _learn_ how to install and configure Apache, there is a plethora of stuff you can search for on the Internet : ))

Comment: I HAVE installed apache,I haven't asked how to install it.

Comment: Command prompt. You go to the directory that Mysql is installed in and run your command. If you have installed Apache, and you don't know what it is, you're following instructions blindly. Read up on WHY you're using the stack you're installing!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost' (using password: NO).
>
> How this problem above is fixed? Please don't tell me to use some kind of code like "mysql -u root -p" because that leads to 2nd question.

This problem is solved by using an account you have set up in MySQL.  Right now you're trying to use the root account with no password specified.  I suggest *not* using the root account, and using a different account you have set up on MySQL.  There are many ways to create accounts.  If  you don't know of one, you can definitely use the MySQL command line client... but you're telling me not to tell you that, so I don't know what you expect.  I guess I'll link you to a tutorial:  https://www.digitalocean.com/community/articles/how-to-create-a-new-user-and-grant-permissions-in-mysql

> If I would use the command above(mysql -u root -p) WHERE do I have to write it in? I mean I have just installed Apache, phpmyadmin, MySQL and php on my computer I haven't even connected it to my website yet(if I have to).

You're using Windows, so fire up the command prompt.  You can do this by clicking start and typing `cmd` into the search box (or clicking run and typing it into the run box on older versions of Windows).  Once there, you can type commands like `mysql` to use the MySQL command-line client.  It's also generally available from your programs menu if you used the MySQL installer.

> What Apache is actually for?What is the purpose of using it?Why would I use it instead of just having my website on any other folder?In which folder should I put my website in(I was thinking about C:\Apache24\htdocs,is that correct?)?

Apache is a web server.  If you expect to have folks access your website, a server needs to send those files to them.  Why would you run one locally?  Something needs to actually run PHP to execute your PHP code.  Your browser doesn't run PHP code.... PHP runs PHP code.  When you use a web server for your local web development, your browser makes a request to it (just as if it were going over the internet), Apache runs PHP to tell it to run your code, your code and PHP send the output HTML to Apache, and then Apache sends that off to your browser.

What directory you put your code in depends entirely on where you installed Apache, and only you know what that is.  But yes, generally there is an `htdocs` directory somewhere.

> Will my configurations work on my website phpmyadmin(which I got when I bought domain which is www.**.com/phpmyadmin) if I haven't connected it to my phpmyadmin which is in apache directory?

What configuration?  I have no idea what you're talking about.  You can install PHPMyAdmin anywhere you want.  I suggest not using it though... it's prone to getting hacked.  Consider something like SQLyog.

> I might ask pretty stupid questions, but please don't judge me, I came to learn, and the purpose of this website is to help, not to flame on others, right?

The purpose of this website is for everyone to learn, not just to help you individually.  The questions you ask aren't stupid, but the way you ask them can be.  Don't tell us that you don't want to hear certain answers, but explain what you have tried and why it didn't work for you.  Don't ask several questions in one big post... ask them separately.  Finally, read the documentation for how to use StackOverflow and how to ask a good question.  You'll get much farther on this site if you ask questions in a way that not only help your immediate problem, but apply to the same problems when others come by later on.  Start with the title of your question.  Do you think that benefits anyone else later on that you need to understand something?  Why not start with, "How to solve 'access denied' errors when to connecting to MySQL"?  Or, "How do I run the MySQL command line client?"  We're not here to help you.  We're here to help everyone, and you are part of that everyone.

Answer (score -1):

If your connecting to local host, use username as root and password blank.

```
 $connection =  mysql_connect("localhost", "root", "") or die ('There is a problem in Username & Password ' . mysql_error());
   $db = mysql_select_db("yourdatabase") or die ('Databse could not be able to selected.' . mysql_error());
   if (!$db)
   {
   echo "DATABASE NOT CONNECT";
    }
```

Comment: That's what he's doing now.